# SQL Statement Construction: Selecting Unique Records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, unique

I currently have a table of Users, and at what time they connected to a device (e.g. a Wifi Router).

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| location_id | device_id | user_id | dwell_time | date                |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
|          14 |         1 |       1 |  27.000000 | 2014-01-04 00:51:12 |
|          15 |         2 |       1 |  12.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:08:56 |
|          16 |         1 |       1 |  12.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:09:26 |
|          17 |         2 |       1 | 318.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:09:38 |
|          18 |         1 |       2 |  20.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:30:03 |
|          19 |         2 |       3 |  20.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:30:03 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
```

I need to write a query title "Get Latest User Connections".

Basically, it needs to go through the history table shown above, and pick the latest record (based on Date) for each user and display it. In the example above, the result should be:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| location_id | device_id | user_id | dwell_time | date                |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
|          17 |         2 |       1 | 318.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:09:38 |
|          18 |         1 |       2 |  20.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:30:03 |
|          19 |         2 |       3 |  20.000000 | 2014-01-04 01:30:03 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------------+
```

Can someone please help me write a SQL statement that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
 from users
 inner join (select user_id,max(date) as maxdate
             from users
             group by user_id)T1
 on T1.user_id = users.user_id
 AND T1.maxdate = users.date
```

or if you don't want to have a subquery, you can user @variables like this query below

```
SELECT location_id,device_id,user_id,dwell_time,date,
       IF(@prevUserId IS NULL OR @prevUserId != user_id,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,
       @prevUserId := user_id
FROM users
HAVING row = 1
ORDER BY user_id,date DESC
```

here's the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f26be/1/0)

Comment: You beat me to it, but forgot to backtick date - let's call it a draw!

Comment: hehe, but date isn't a reserved word.

Comment: I thought it should be since there are so many date functions

Comment: I definitly thought it was - what a nice day to learn something new.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response @TinTran! I wish I could accept both your answers.

Comment: I voted up the other answer so they @Eugen Rieck can get some points too hehe

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the combination of `user_id` and `date` is unique in the table, you could

```
SELECT
  tablename.*
FROM tablename
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(`date`) AS maxdate
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) AS selector
  ON tablename.user_id=selector.user_id AND tablename.`date`=selector.maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.location_id, u.device_id, u.user_id, u.dwell_time, u.datec
FROM (SELECT u.location_id, u.device_id, u.user_id, u.dwell_time, u.date 
      FROM users u ORDER BY u.user_id, u.date DESC
     ) A 
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT u.location_id, u.device_id, u.user_id, u.dwell_time, u.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT u.user_id, MAX(u.date) AS latestDate 
            FROM users u GROUP BY u.user_id
           ) A ON u.user_id = A.user_id AND A.latestDate = u.date
```